# KSQL: Jackson error when attempting to select * from stream

Tags: ksqldb

This question is based on the solution path in [KSQL stream from topic with heterogeneous JSON structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840974/) - I get an error when I try to `select` from a stream created from a topic with a `value_format='json'`. 
 I can still `print` the underlying topic, but doing `select * from stream;` throws an error.

We're using Confluent 5.3.1 aka Kafka 2.3.1.

Here's how I (re)create the issue...

1. Start with some simple json data

```
ksql> PRINT 'sms-reporting.status-updated';
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1573688864403,"ROWKEY":"null","acceptTs":"1573603201000","eventType":"REPORTING","isFinal":"true","messageId":"8619Z-1113H-00007-01CF5","nodeId":"86","responseCode":"3041","submissionAttempt":"1","ts":"1573603201567","type":"statusUpdated"}
```

2. Create the stream:

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM statusupdated ( \
 acceptTs VARCHAR, \
 eventType VARCHAR, \
 isFinal VARCHAR, \
 messageId VARCHAR, \
 nodeId VARCHAR, \
 responseCode VARCHAR, \
 submissionAttempt VARCHAR, \
 ts VARCHAR, \
 type VARCHAR \
) with (kafka_topic='sms-reporting.status-updated',value_format='json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> DESCRIBE statusupdated;

Name                 : STATUSUPDATED
 Field             | Type
-----------------------------------------------
 ROWTIME           | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY            | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 ACCEPTTS          | VARCHAR(STRING)
 EVENTTYPE         | VARCHAR(STRING)
 ISFINAL           | VARCHAR(STRING)
 MESSAGEID         | VARCHAR(STRING)
 NODEID            | VARCHAR(STRING)
 RESPONSECODE      | VARCHAR(STRING)
 SUBMISSIONATTEMPT | VARCHAR(STRING)
 TS                | VARCHAR(STRING)
 TYPE              | VARCHAR(STRING)
-----------------------------------------------
```

3. Attempt (unsuccessfully) to review the contents of the stream:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM statusupdated;
Query terminated
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "terminal" (class io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "finalMessage", "row", "errorMessage"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"row":{"columns":[1573692743435,null,"1573603201000","REPORTING","true","8619Z-1113H-00007-01CF5","86","3041","1","1573603201567","statusUpdated"]},"errorMessage":null,"finalMessage":null,"terminal":false}"; line: 1, column: 206] (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow["terminal"])
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "terminal" (class io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "finalMessage", "row", "errorMessage"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"row":{"columns":[1573692743435,null,"1573603201000","REPORTING","true","8619Z-1113H-00007-01CF5","86","3041","1","1573603201567","statusUpdated"]},"errorMessage":null,"finalMessage":null,"terminal":false}"; line: 1, column: 206] (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow["terminal"])
Caused by: Unrecognized field "terminal" (class io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "finalMessage", "row", "errorMessage"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"row":{"columns":[1573692743435,null,"1573603201000","REPORTING","true","8619Z-1113H-00007-01CF5","86","3041","1","1573603201567","statusUpdated"]},"errorMessage":null,"finalMessage":null,"terminal":false}"; line: 1, column: 206] (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow["terminal"])
```

If I now use this stream (on which I still cannot execute a `select` statement without receiving an error) to create *another* stream (which will, of course, be backed by a *new* topic), I still can't `select` on the new stream, **but** I *can* `print` the new backing topic and the data appears as expected.

4. Create a derived stream

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM statusupdated2 AS SELECT acceptts FROM statusupdated;

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql> describe statusupdated2;

Name                 : STATUSUPDATED2
 Field    | Type
--------------------------------------
 ROWTIME  | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY   | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 ACCEPTTS | VARCHAR(STRING)
--------------------------------------
```

5. Attempt (unsuccessfully) to review the contents of the derived stream:

```
ksql> SELECT * FROM statusupdated2;
Query terminated
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "terminal" (class io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "finalMessage", "row", "errorMessage"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"row":{"columns":[1573692743435,null,"1573603201000"]},"errorMessage":null,"finalMessage":null,"terminal":false}"; line: 1, column: 113] (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow["terminal"])
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "terminal" (class io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "finalMessage", "row", "errorMessage"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"row":{"columns":[1573692743435,null,"1573603201000"]},"errorMessage":null,"finalMessage":null,"terminal":false}"; line: 1, column: 113] (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow["terminal"])
Caused by: Unrecognized field "terminal" (class io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "finalMessage", "row", "errorMessage"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"row":{"columns":[1573692743435,null,"1573603201000"]},"errorMessage":null,"finalMessage":null,"terminal":false}"; line: 1, column: 113] (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.StreamedRow["terminal"])
```

6. `print` the backing topic of the new stream:

```
ksql> PRINT statusupdated2;
Format:JSON
{"ROWTIME":1573692743435,"ROWKEY":"null","ACCEPTTS":"1573603201000"}
```

Comment: This seems to me like you may be using a mismatching version of the CLI and your server. We removed the `terminal` field from the message that is being sent from the server. We also added `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to make sure that any future CLIs reading the old data would just ignore it. When you startup KSQL, what does it say as the CLI/Server version on the splash screen?

Comment: I shall investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

> SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';

before running the select query ?

Comment: Whether set to 'earliest' or 'latest', the ```select * from statusupdated``` returns the error message.